# How do I access the properties of a contract xyz from an enclosing contract abc?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, truffle, contract-invocation

With respect to the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract xyz {
   uint x = 0;

   function setX(uint pX) public {
       x = pX;
   }

   function getX() public view returns(uint){
       return x;
   }
}

contract abc{
    xyz public obj = new xyz();

    function getValueOfObj() public view returns(uint){
        return obj.getX();
    }

    function setValueOfObj(uint pX) public{
        obj.setX(pX);
    }
}
```

I am working in truffle console and I use:

```
var abcDeployed = abc.deployed().then((i) => {abcDeployed = i});
var xyzDeployed = xyz.deployed().then((i) => {xyzDeployed = i});
var contractXYZ = web3.eth.contract(xyzDeployed.abi, xyzDeployed.address);
var contractXYZInstance = contractXYZ.at(abcDeployed.obj());
```

And when I try to call:

```
contractXYZInstance.getX()
Error: invalid address
```

How do I access the properties of contract `xyz` from the contract `abc` in truffle console or using `web3`?

Comment: You might want to print out the return value of `abcDeployed.obj()` to see what that's returning.

Comment: For example: abcDeployed.obj() is returning this 0x23cba2a17c44171894a7cd2ae9b807282bd1c323

Comment: That address looks fine. Perhaps it's the `from` address of the transaction? Maybe use an explicit `from` address.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score -1):

If you are deploying both contracts, you will need to have the second contract reference the address of the first contract.

Something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Contract1 {
   uint x = 0;

   function setX(uint pX) public {
       x = pX;
   }

   function getX() public view returns(uint){
       return x;
   }
}

contract Contract2{
    Contract1 contract1;

    function setContract1 (address addr) public {
        contract1 = Contract1(addr);
    }

    function getValueOfObj() public view returns(uint){
        return contract1.getX();
    }

    function setValueOfObj(uint pX) public{
        contract1.setX(pX);
    }
}
```

Then, once you set the correct address within the second contract, you can simply call the functions from the second contract, which will pull and push to the first contract.

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to the question, where one contract is deployed by the other.

Comment: I think I misunderstood then

Comment: This method is not feasible if I have many contract objects and if  they also have many properties.